# angularjs - dynamic function return

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-loop

index.html

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-style="getStyle(object.id)"></div>
```

controller.js

```
[...]

$scope.startWidth = 100;

$scope.getObject = [...]

$scope.getStyle = function(id) {
   var widthVal = $scope.startWidth;
   $scope.StartWidth += $scope.getObject(id).value;
   return { width : widthVal }
}

[...]
```

This code runs into an infinite $digest loop. I think i know why. The return value should not to be dynamic. But how can i realize that without the loop? I want to display objects with different width. The width of an object depends on a value of the previous object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Ilan's problem description and solution - it works in case the `objects` array is not going to change, otherwise the widths will be calculated incorrectly. If new objects may be added/removed in runtime then it is better to recalculate the widths when the collection is changed (see `$watchCollection` method of scope) or on each digest cycle (for short list of elements it shall be fast enough), something like that:

```
  var widths = [];
  $scope.$watch(function calculateWidths() {
    var tempWidth = 0;
    widths = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.objects, function(obj) {
      tempWidth += obj.value;
      widths.push(tempWidth);
    });
  });

  $scope.getStyle = function(idx){
    return {width: widths[idx] + 'px'}
  }
```

[Here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nEwlIXnliffuxPPwapjB?p=preview)

Comment: Nice work, I improved my answer based on your approach

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `ng-style` puts a `$watchExpression` on each child scope.

A `$watchExpression` must be **idempotent**, means it must return the same with multiple checks.
If a `$watchExpression` is **still dirty** another `$digest` will be triggered.

#### UPDATE

After I saw **GRaAL** nice answer I came up with even better solution:

Here is a demo plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/oPrTiwTOyCR3khs2iVga?p=preview

**controller:**

```
$scope.$watchCollection('objects', function calculateWidths() {
  var tempWidth = 0;
  for( var i = 0; i < $scope.objects.length; i++) {
    tempWidth += $scope.objects[i].value;
    $scope.objects[i].width = tempWidth + 'px';
  }
});
```

**markup:**

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-style="{width: object.width}">
```

#### old solution

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/CqxOmV5lpZSLKxqT4yqo?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Because of the changes in `objects` array i use the solution of GRaAL